# Custom filtering With Button for Datatable is not working

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I am using Datatable for my current project. In one of my table, I have several columns. One of the columns is 'Status' column that will have one of three values 'inactive', 'no pan card', and 'Approved'. I want to filter the record that shown in the table with three buttons, 'In Progress' and 'Closed', like this. but it showing nothing, can anybody help me:

```
$('#tabledata').DataTable();

    var dataTables = $('#tabledata').DataTable({
    "info": false,
    "lengthChange": false
});

$('#onprogress').on('click', function () {
    dataTables.columns(11).search("Inactive").draw();
});

     $("body").on("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

});